# Apache 2.4, Windows 10 and password protected directories

Tags: apache, passwords, config

I've been trying to install password protection in a subdirectory of my Apache 2.4 (Windows 10) htdocs directory.

I started with an external .htaccess file and migrated to adding the data to a  entyr in the httpd.conf file.

I place the .htpasswd file in the directory above htdocs (root?) and refer to the directory as '/.htaccess'. I ran Process Monitor (formerly from SysInternals) and know the .htpasswd and .htaccess files were being found and read.

I access the protected directory using three different addresses:127.0.0.1(localhost);192.168.0.101; and 'jimjulian.ddns.net'.

In each case, the password form pops up once, I fill out the form, get entry and close. In each case, I have access from then on, without the form.

I tried erasing the browser (Chrome) cache, but to no end.

Is there anything I've overlooked? Anything I can try?

.htaccess contents:

```
AuthType Basic
AuthName 'Area51'
AuthUserFile 'C:\Apache24\.htpasswd'
require valid-user
```

I wasn't sure what to do with the AllowOverride. Seemed to me, the default setting, None, would nullify the contents of the .htaccess
So I set that to All in the conf file

Answer (score 0):

Two revelations solved the problem. 
My dns updater for No-IP was not running.
Even though I cleared the browsing history and cache regularly, I didn't realize until just now, and after installing another browser for comparisons, that passwords and usernames were being held the length of the session. Once I closed the browser and reopened, and cleared the cache again, the password popup, popped up. Perhaps this will benefit someone.